# Routing within server cluster for websockets

Tags: java, websocket, microservices, publish-subscribe

Our backend has a need for real-time communication with our front-end. We intend to create a **Websocket Microservice (WM)** in Java that our clients will connect to. Our different backend services will push messages to the WM for specific users, and the WM will push those messages to the target connected clients over the websocket connections. The WM is a cluster, so for a specific message to reach a specific user, that message needs to be routed to the specific server that holds the connection for that user. The WM needs to scale to 1 million+ client connections, but any given message will be intended for only a handful of users.

For routing, I have considered pub sub with an individual topic per user, but I don't know if this is scalable in the way we need. We could also broadcast the backend messages to all servers in the cluster, but this is not horizontally scalable, as each server would need to handle more and more messages as volume increases.

**What would be an ideal, horizontally scalable way to route backend messages to the correct server instance that holds the connection for the recipient user?**